One glossary-mcols column disappears when using polyglossia with a RTL language
Here's my MWE:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{leipzig} %for linguistic abbreviations that go into the glossary
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew} %this is the line that causes the erroneous output

\begin{document}

Items that will be in my glossary: {\Sg} {\Pl} {\Pst} {\Fut} 

\printglossary[style=mcolindex]

\end{document}

There should be four items in my glossary, split into two columns of two items each, like this:

However, this is what gets output by the MWE above:


I can't reproduce your problem. Try with babel + lualatex instead.

@UlrikeFischer You're right, I tried on a different machine and couldn't reproduce the problem either. Any ideas what could be going wrong? I was using TeXstudio when I encountered the issue.

the editor doesn't matter. Compare the log-files to find the relevant differences.
